# Find time needed for vertices to stop disappearing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given undirected graph that consists of N vertices numbered from 0 to N-1 connected with M edges.The graph is described by two arrays, A and B both of length M. A pair ([A[k],B[k]) describes edge between A[k] and B[k] for k from 0 to M-1.

Each second every vertex with at most 1 edge connected to disappears.Every edge which is connected to one of disappearing vertices also disappears.

After how many seconds will the vertices stop disappearing.

For N=7, ((0,1),(1,2),(2,0),(1,4),(4,5),(4,6)) answer should be 2.

```
def solution(N,A,B):

    d2 = dict.fromkeys(range(N), 0)

    count = 0
    arr = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        arr.append((A[i],B[i]))
    while True:
        for i in range(len(A)+1):
            for c in arr:
                if i in c:
                    d2[i] += 1
        arr1 = arr
        for i in range(len(A)+1):
               if d2[i] <= 1:


                   arr = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] != i and x[0] != i, arr))

        if len(arr) == len(arr1):
            return count + 1
            break
        count += 1
```

Here is my code.For this test case  (4, [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0]) it outputs Keyerror: 4. Can you help me to solve the problem.Thank you.

Comment: "it outputs runtime error" -- please specify the runtime error by posting the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I inserted a couple of `print()` to let you see what's going on):

```
def solution(N, A, B):
    linked = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        linked[A[i]].append(B[i])
        linked[B[i]].append(A[i])
    changed = True
    seconds = 0
    removing = []
    while changed:
        changed = False
        seconds += 1
        print(f'second {seconds}')
        for i in list(linked.keys())[:]:
            if len(linked[i]) > 1:
                continue
            if len(linked[i]) == 1:
                   removing.append((linked[i][0],i))
            del linked[i]
            changed = True
        for i,j in removing:
            print(f'remove {j} from {i}')
            linked[i].remove(j)
        removing = []
    return seconds - 1
```